# Pandas - Convert Text To Binary Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe "df":

```
    ph_level
0   low
1   medium
2   low
3   high
4   low
5   medium
```

I would like to add 3 binary columns for the low,medium,high data. Below is the output I am seeking:

```
    ph_level low_binary  medium_binary  high_binary
0   low      1           0              0 
1   medium   0           1              0
2   low      1           0              0
3   high     0           0              1
4   low      1           0              0
5   medium   0           1              0
```

Is there a very fast way to do this with pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pandas.get_dummies` and concatenate the result with the original data frame:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.ph_level).rename(columns = "{}_binary".format)], axis = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Super fast! Thank you Psidom.